# Laptop screen goes blank on reducing brightness

Tags: power-management, screen, brightness, battery

Immediately when I reduce brightness, the screen goes blank. 
The screen also goes blank when I plug out and plug back in the AC adapter.
Only the screen goes blank, the laptop is on.
And it is not fully blank, i can see faint outlines of the windows on screen.
There is no issue if I do not change brightness or AC adapter. If I run only on battery, no problem. But the moment I plug in the adapter, the screen goes off. It comes back on when I press the power button (it suspends the laptop), and then I press it back to wake it, it comes back.

What happened? Can anyone please help!

Using 18.04

Tried fresh copy of Xubuntu too, same issue

Comment: What make and model of laptop?

Comment: Thinkpad W541 Lenovo